# Bootstrap 3 carousel - only caption, flexible height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm trying to create a Testimonials section on my website using Bootstrap carousel - each one as a separate slide. I got to the point of having only text, but I don't see a way of adjusting the height automatically. The desired result is the height of the slide depending on the amount of text in each testimonial.

Here's the code so far:

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="new_html_code">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In quam nisl, volutpat vel ullamcorper id, tempor sagittis nisl. Duis sit amet fermentum nisl. Aenean ante sem, pretium sit amet elit sit amet, rhoncus ullamcorper dolor. Nam pellentesque justo sed faucibus sodales. Fusce feugiat elit lectus, nec bibendum eros adipiscing ut. Etiam ac laoreet eros. Phasellus quis vestibulum purus. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- more slides -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.new_html_code {
    width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;    
}
```

If I remove the height, the text simply dissapears. What can I do to achieve the desired result?